# Heatsink calculation for a MOSFET in active mode

Tags: mosfet, heatsink

Actually I am working on a project to create an electronic load for power supplies, batteries... testing. The circuit is already designed but I am working now in the heat disipation of the mosfet in such conditions.

I want to make it able to simulate loads up to 100W, so the mosfet will have to disipate almost all the power (wich is a lot). Searching on internet I was able to calculate the requied max Rsa for the heatsink thanks to this formula:

Rsa = (Tj - Ta) / Pd - (Rjc + Rcs)

Now I know that I need a heatsink with an Rsa of less than 1ºC/W but the most of heatsinks I see doesn't provide that info, just the materials and sizes.

Someone can help me with info about how to calculate the Thermal Resistance of a HeatSink?.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably have your question closed because questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic on this site so you might want to remove that part. Start by looking at the major supplier's catalogues. When you find an interesting heatsink then get its datasheet and see what you can learn from that. Bear in mind that a long heatsink will probably be rated for several components mounted along it's length. If you're just putting one great big heat source in the middle you're likely to be disappointed due to the thermal gradient along the device.

Comment: I'm not searching for products recommendations, I'm looking for help for calculating/select the right size/materials of the heatsink, or by defaut, any book, article or similar with info about it... For products I have a lot of sites where to take a look, but I've seen that there are a lot of sites where there is no info about the Heatsink Rsa, just a datasheet of material and sizes, and that is my question, how to calculate the Rsa of those heatsinks to know if is the right choice.

Comment: You should have listened ... Your looking for books and articles in your last paragraph. Fix the question and you should be able to get it reopened.

Comment: Fixed... Anyway, is not the first time I see a link to an article in StackExchange with some info about how to fix the problem. What I mean is that I've asked for it because it's a very extense post and I thought that was allowed.

Comment: Because the contributors to the site all want the site to be better and also want to help, combined with the complexity of the topics, we're constantly trying to make questions better, and also letting something slide in almost any question.  When I see a high quality question that's within my expertise, I experience a much stronger motivation to write a high quality answer than if the motivation is just to help out.  A low quality question is one that helps only one person or does not stand up over time.

Comment: I've actually researched this topic before, and the beginner level answers to your question are on stack exchange in other questions, but I don't remember where.  At it's simplest you basically treat blocks of thermally conductive materials as thermal resistors similar to electrical resistors to calculate the thermal gradient over them and resultant temperatures.  This can be made kind of simple for unnecessarily thick heat sinks, but for ones that maximise material usage or take advantage of phase change effects like heat pipes, it becomes much easier to either simulate or simply test.

Comment: That said, you have a 100W semiconductor load.  Have you considered a 100W CPU heatsink and fan arrangement?  If you care about weight vs performance, that's probably the cheapest way you'll get something with heat pipes in it(heat pipes are great but beware they can be destroyed by subzero temperatures depending on the fluid inside).  For simple geometries with no heat pipes, like an extruded heat sink with a thick base and thin fins, You can calculate the thermal gradient over the base based on the heat source and it's material and thickness, and then apply the temperatures at the base of

Comment: each fin to calculate the thermal gradient over the fins.  Then you can use the resulting temperature to calculate thermal dissipation to the ambient air based on air flow rate, surface properties of the heatsink and air temperature.  I don't understand the topic well enough to write you an answer.  Have you checked out readily available heat sink calculators like this one? https://celsiainc.com/resources/calculators/heat-sink-calculator/

Comment: Hello, thanks. I've searched on Google without find any good result. The most talks about to calculate the Rsa in the mosfet side, and others just don't give enough information to do it by myself. I've not fully searched on the site, but the results that gave me the title were not exactly what I want. I'll give try to the computer fan or the calculator, and I'll try to continue researching to find the way to do it by myself.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the vast majority of us don't even try to calculate the thermal resistance of a heatsink...the manufacturer of the heatsink should provide that information. If you aren't finding that specification, look at some other manufacturer's websites. Don't look at **vendor** websites, just the manufacturer's websites.